# How to add a Reviewer to azure devops pull request using Git Bash

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, git-bash

How do I create a pull request with a reviewer name included using Git Bash to Azure DevOps?

I've tried making a pull request in the Azure DevOps UI, but the UI is clunky, and would rather use Git Bash.

Comment: What do you mean "using Git Bash"? Making an API call from the command line? Have you done any research around this (e.g. reading the API docs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could expand the Git aliases with VSTS CLI commands to achieve it.

There is [VSTS CLI interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/install?view=vsts-cli-latest) that you can [configure the VSTS CLI to add git aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/git?view=vsts-cli-latest) for common git-based VSTS CLI commands like creating or adding reviewers to pull requests.

Add reviewers to a pull request:

VSTS CLI Command  : `vsts code pr reviewers add --id # --reviewers {name}`

git alias command : `git pr reviewers add --id # --reviewers {name}`

You can also refer to this guide [docs](http://hermit.no/visual-studio-and-azure-devops-git-extend-the-git-command-line-with-server-commands-part-2/) .